# Finding x according to a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $x > 0$. Define a sequence for $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ in the following way:
$$a_1 = x\\ a_2 = x^x \\ a_3 = x^{x^x}\\
a_4 = x^{x^{x^x}}$$

If you know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=5$$ then what is $x$?

Comment: Please check if the edit is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}=x^{a_n}$$
Applying limit,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{a_n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=x^{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}$$
$$5=x^5$$
$$x=\sqrt[5]5$$

---

Alternatively,
observe that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\ldots}}}}}}=x^{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}}$$
then similarly,
$$x^5=5$$

Answer (score 2):

Write it out as

$$ x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}} = 5 $$
and notice that the exponent on $x$ is the same as the expression on the LHS. So we can rewrite as

$$ x^5 = 5 $$

and this is easily solved from here.